# Grafico Passando dados php para js

Tags: php, javascript, div, gráfico

Olá,

Tenho um arquivo em php com uma div chamando o arquivo js, mas preciso que o arquivo js leia os dados do php

no arquvio php:

```
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

no arquivo js:

```
    function mainChart(){

  var color1 = App.color.primary;
  var color2 = tinycolor( App.color.primary ).lighten( 13 ).toString();
  var color3 = tinycolor( App.color.primary ).lighten( 20 ).toString();

  var data = [
    [1, 35],
    [2, 60],
    [3, 40],
    [4, 65],
    [5, 45],
    [6, 75],
    [7, 35],
    [8, 40],
    [9, 60]
  ];
```

no lugar desse array fixo tenho que buscar esses dados no Banco
ficaria lago assim:

```
function mainChart(){

    var color1 = App.color.primary;
    var color2 = tinycolor( App.color.primary ).lighten( 13 ).toString();
    var color3 = tinycolor( App.color.primary ).lighten( 20 ).toString();

    var data = [
        <?php
        $i = '0';
        foreach ($ConsultasCanceladas as $canceladas) {
            $i = ++$i;
            echo "['" . $i . "', " . $canceladas->dt_consulta . "],";
        }
        ?>
    ];
```

O que acontece é que o arquivo js nao aceita o php

Comment: Coloca essa função mainChart dentro do arquivo PHP, ou então utiliza AJAX pra pegar esses dados.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode obter os dados para o seu Javascript utilizando AJAX, ou pode optar por colocar algumas classes no seu HTML e pegar via JQuery ou Javascript puro mesmo.

Exemplos:

- Usando JQuery:   $(".elementos")
- Usando JS Puro:  var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("elementos");